# jQuery location href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I remember there's a redirect function in jQuery.

It was like:

```
$(location).href('http://address.com')
```

But what was it exactly? I couldn't remember and can't find it using Google Search.

Comment: `$(location).attr('href','http://address.com');`

Comment: To clarify other answers, be aware that (a) you don't need jQuery for this; the native approach is perfectly sound; (b) jQuery is just a library of functions; (c) you're still writing _Javascript_.

Comment: $(location) is a selector to instruct Query to refer to the DOM object called location. 

The object location is an object containing some properties, like href (see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)

The property href indicates simply the URL opened in the browser window.

Everytime you change it the browser load the new URL.

So in the code you indicated you are changing the href property of the DOM object location, using a jQuery style.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There's no need for jQuery.

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

Answer (score 32):

Use:

```
window.location.replace(...)
```

See this Stack Overflow question for more information:

*[How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/)*

Or perhaps it was this you remember:

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
location.href = url;
```

Comment: Answer is on this link. Can I add this to my question to find ppl it easily? Is it legal? Or what must i do?

Comment: Could mark this case as duplicate of that one?

Comment: You fail to explain that the replace makes you unable to navigate back to the current page after the redirect.

Answer (score 29):

This is easier:

```
location.href = 'http://address.com';
```

Or

```
location.replace('http://address.com'); // <-- No history saved.
```

Answer (score 13):

I think you are looking for:

```
window.location = 'http://someUrl.com';
```

It's not jQuery; it's pure JavaScript.

Comment: No, I was looking for by jquery. I've found.

Comment: @jammypeach: jQuery is Javascript. Javascript is not jQuery.

Answer (score 8):

Ideally, you want to be using `window.location.replace(...)`.

See this answer here for a full explanation: *[How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery)*

Answer (score 6):

You can use just JavaScript:

```
window.location = 'http://address.com';
```