# Can I execute a link after a preventDefault()?

Tags: jquery

Code :

```
$('#myLink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    ...

    if (someCondition) {
        ... code ...
    } else {
        ... execute the link
    }
});
```

I'd like, if `someCondition` is false, execute the original href of the link (so, go that link, changing the page). Is it this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move the `preventDefault` inside the if/else statement:

```
$('#myLink').click(function (e) {

    ...

    if (someCondition) {
        e.preventDefault();

        ... code ...

    } else {
        ... execute the link
    }
});
```

Comment: depending on how long your conditional takes the browse might follow the original link before reaching that part of the code.

Comment: And that deserves a -1? LOL ok

Comment: Yes, because the answer is incorrect and misleading.

Comment: @deweydb Well then add an answer that is correct and not misleading.

Comment: ubercooluk's answer is fine and i voted for that one. no need to ad another.

Answer (score 27):

```
$('#myLink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    ...

    if (someCondition) {
      //do stuff
    } else {
        location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that this opens the link in the same tab even if it was clicked with CMD (Mac) or CTRL (Windows, Ubuntu) pressed.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look: [Jquery Location Href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078660/jquery-location-href)

Basically you can use `window.location.href = 'http://example.com';`

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `e.preventDefault();` inside the condition?

Comment: You are right, but a small note in the case of working with AJAX, you must 
cast
e.preventionDefault() before starting your ajax and checking, this is in case you need to check something with ajax, in which case your answer won't work