# Performing methods in click() function before href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button with a `href` that sends data, and before that I want to show a popup using `Bootbox.js`

HTML:

```
<a href="submit?result=something"> 
  <button class="alert btn btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
</a>
```

JS:

```
$('alert').click(function(){
    bootbox.alert("Submitted!", function() {
        console.log("Alert Callback");
    });
});
```

This just performs the `href` action so it does not display the popup using `Bootbox.js`. Is there a way to perform a function and perform the href right after you close this?

For reference: http://bootboxjs.com

Comment: Trigger the `href` explicitly in the bootbox callback.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078660/jquery-location-href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can remove the the hyperlink from the HTML markup, just keep the button and then do something like this:-

```
$('.alert').click(function(){
    bootbox.alert("Submitted!", function() {
        console.log("Alert Callback");
        window.location.href = '/submit?result=something';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return false;`:

```
$('.alert').click(function(e){ // missed the . for the class selector
    bootbox.alert("Submitted!", function() {
        location.href = this.parentNode.href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

---

Another suggestion is to use `data-*` attribute on button itself instead of wrapping it within an anchor:

```
<button class="alert btn btn-primary" data-href="submit?result=something" type="button">Submit</button>
```

then you can use this:

```
$('.alert').click(function(e){ // missed the . for the class selector
    bootbox.alert("Submitted!", function() {
        location.href = this.dataset['href'];
    });
});
```